# Scala wildcard for recursive generic definition

Tags: scala, generics, types, existential-type

Suppose there is the following trait definition:

`trait MyTrait[A, B <: MyTrait[A, B]]` which has an implementation:

`class MyClass extends MyTrait[Int, MyClass]`

Hot to write the signature of a generic partial function to filter any instances of `MyTrait`?

```
def filterMyTrait: PartialFunction[MyTrait[_, _], Boolean] = {
  case myClass: MyClass => true
}
```

or

```
def filterMyTrait: PartialFunction[MyTrait[_, _ <: MyTrait[_, _]], Boolean]  = {
  case myClass: MyClass => true
}
```

both fail at compile time with

`type arguments [_$1,_$2] do not conform to trait MyTrait's type parameter bounds [A,B <: MyTrait[A,B]]
  def filterMyTrait: PartialFunction[MyTrait[_, _ <: MyTrait[_, _]], Boolean] = {`

Comment: What scala version are you using?

Comment: @IvanStanislavciuc 2.12.8

Comment: @m3th0dman Both your definitions compile in 2.12.8 https://scastie.scala-lang.org/VGXcHFPwSpCsqtYetTqgcA You should provide more details.

Comment: @DmytroMitin My bad; I didn't provide any implementation. Check this out: https://scastie.scala-lang.org/bYZrlk4WQAqLL0sxOiYIDQ

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to make your method generic

```
def filterMyTrait[A, B <: MyTrait[A, B]]: PartialFunction[MyTrait[A, B], Boolean] = {
  case myClass: MyClass => true
}
```

or use existential type

```
def filterMyTrait: PartialFunction[MyTrait[A, B] forSome {type A; type B <: MyTrait[A, B]}, Boolean] = {
  case myClass: MyClass => true
}
```